# Using Quotes in command line arguments

Tags: c++, cmd, codeblocks

I tried coding programs  which have command line arguments as input. When i used command line arguments inside quotes  in cmd like

`g++ -o filename.exe filename.cpp  // for compiling`

and

`filename.exe  "2 -1 0 2 -3" // run command`

answer was incorrect. But when i used

`g++ -o filename.exe filename.cpp  // for compiling`

`filename.exe  2 -1 0 2 -3  // run command`

answer is correct......why is it happening...can someone suggest something to rectify it pls....i used c++ to code and  cmd to complie and run and test.

Comment: Anything in quotes is passed as **one** argument.

Comment: Quotes in CMD escape most of its special characters, but they don't have anything to do with CMD passing *arguments* to a program. The quoting is parsed partially by CMD to find the file to run if it's quoted. Otherwise it gets parsed by the process itself. Windows programs are executed with a command-line string, and they commonly use either the [C runtime to parse arguments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/cpp/parsing-cpp-command-line-arguments) or call `CommandLineToArgvW`, which uses similar rules.

Answer (score 1):

> You pass all the command line arguments separated by a **space**, but if
>   argument itself has a space then you can pass such arguments by
>   putting them inside double quotes **""** or single quotes **''**.

So

```
"2 -1 0 2 -3"  // One argument
```

while

```
2 -1 0 2 -3    // Five arguments
```

You can combine them

```
"2 -1 0" 2 -3  // Three arguments
```

The command line arguments are handled using `main()` function arguments where argc refers to the number of arguments passed, and argv[] is a pointer array which points to each argument passed to the program.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { ... }
```

Where `argv[0]` is always program name. In your case `filename.exe`.